# Trying to get the name of each user in my MongoDB Database

Tags: c#, mongodb, console-application

i have a MongoDB Database for my discord but i'm making a simple c# app that will access the database and show each users name and level this is my current code

```cs
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace ExampleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            MongoClient dbClient = new MongoClient("Connection String");

            var database = dbClient.GetDatabase("test");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("users");
            var firstDocument = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ForEachAsync(user =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(user);
            });
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

i can't figure out how to print each users name and level like `user.name` or `user.level` isn't a thing

Comment: Would be great if you can share the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the properties of the BsonDocument like this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{user["name"].AsString} - {user["level"].AsInt32}");
```

The indexer is used to retrieve the value. Based on this, you can use the `As*`-properties to convert the value to the desired data type. Above sample assumes that `name` is a string and `level` is an Int32 (int).